# LineLegend only contains one element

Tags: plotting, legending

I'm having trouble getting all of my lines within a Plot[] rendering to be presented in the legend.  Below I illustrate the problem.  I create 4 different lines in Plot[] but the legend only has the first entry.

```
(*set up functions*)
piFunction = (1 - Exp[-Δx a])/(1 - 
    Exp[-Δx 2 Ne]);(*StatMech Fixation Pr*)
rate = 
 mu 2/a Ne piFunction;(*Subscript[q,ij]:rate of transitioning from i \
to j*)
logRate = Log[10, rate] // Simplify;
logRateApproxList = 
  Table[Series[logRate, {Δx, 0, order}] // 
     Simplify, {order, 1, 20}] // Normal;
logRateApproxListLargeNe = 
  logRateApproxList /. {a -> 0, 
     mu -> 1, Δx -> Δy/Ne} // Cancel;
(*Plot subset of Functions*)

subList = {3, 7, 11, 15};
Plot[logRateApproxListLargeNe[[subList]], {Δy, -4, 4}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Δx Ne", "Θ"}, 
 Evaluated -> True, PlotStyle -> Automatic, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  LineLegend[subList, LegendMarkers -> Automatic, 
   LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, RoundingRadius -> 5] &), 
   LegendLabel -> 
    Column[{"Δx", "Approximation Order"}]]]
```

And here's the output,

[image: Plot with 4 function evaluations but only one entry in the legend]

Please note I would like to utilize the PlotStyle->Automatic functionality rather than having to define the PlotStyle explicitly.

I'm using Mathematica 10.4.1 on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: This is a known problem (and duplicate); `Evaluated -> True` doesn't work well with legends.  use `Evaluate @ logRateApproxListLargeNe[[subList]]` instead, but be mindful that does not localize the Plot variables.

Comment: I think it should also be pointed out that `Evaluated` is undocumented, so while it works in most cases, it can't be trusted to work in all cases.

Comment: @rcollyer How is it that needful things like `Evaluated` are relegated to "undocumented" and "can't be trusted" while the function bloat continues?  Gah...

Comment: @Mr.Wizard it lacks documentation, and like all such functions ... as to the function bloat, I'm no where near the strategy meetings so I can't comment.

Comment: @rcollyer Sorry, just venting nebulous disappointment.  :-(

Comment: @Mr.Wizard duly noted. There are always things we (on the inside) wish were included, too. But, schedules get away from us, and perfection is the enemy of the good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is often better to wrap the functions in `Evaluate[]` rather than set `Evaluated->True`:

```
Plot[Evaluate[
  logRateApproxListLargeNe[[subList]]], {Δy, -4, 4}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Δx Ne", "Θ"}, 
 PlotStyle -> Automatic, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  LineLegend[subList, LegendMarkers -> Automatic, 
   LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, RoundingRadius -> 5] &), 
   LegendLabel -> 
    Column[{"Δx", "Approximation Order"}]]]
```

[image]

- You may wish to wrap the `Plot` expression in `Block[{Δy}, (* Plot *)]` if there is any chance that `Δy` may have a global value.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Well, to be honest it might as well just have been a comment. But I tend to overlook that when a Q gets no attention for 20 mins. I can delete if you think best.

Comment: No, you put in the time to write the answer, there is no need to delete it.  I merely wanted to point out that there is also reason to use `Evaluated -> True`, documented or not.